# search (Xpath) then clicking ABOVE and NEXT cell

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I had to find some style using Xpath
then i had to click above line with different cell  (different tr, different td)

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Random Number</td>
    <td><a>Random Title</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Random Number</td>
    <td><a>Random Title</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Random Number</td>
    <td><a>Random Title</a></td>   << 2.then go ABOVE lines and .click() NEXT td
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><em style=color:red>Random Number</em></td>   << 1. Had to find this 
    <td><a>Random Title</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried as below code, but it failed.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//tbody//tr[last()-1]//td//em[@style='color:red']//em"
).click()
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath.

```
//tr[td/em[@style='color:red']]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[2]/a
```

Here is the explanation for the xpath that I derived above.
Let me split the xpath into 4 parts

- finding cell contains the reference (em with style in this case)

  > //td/em[@style='color:red']
- finding the row  containing the above td (we are targeting the row so we should remove `//` in the above xpath

  > //tr[td/em[@style='color:red']]  <<--- this will achieve your first step in mission
- finding the previous row (preceding-sibling will find all the previous elements in the same level of current element, so we have to filter the desired elements with `::desired_tag` in this case it's row so we used `preceding-sibling::tr`.

  > //tr[td/em[@style='color:red']]/preceding-sibling::tr

  But when you say `preceding-sibling::tr` it will filter all previous rows, so added `[1]` as we want the immediate previous row in this case. If you want the second previous row then you have to add `[2]`.

  > //tr[td/em[@style='color:red']]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]
- finding the target link (as you are in the desired row, now you can simply traverse to the link)

  > //tr[td/em[@style='color:red']]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[2]/a

*Note: Refered Nodes as elements for better understanding in the above explanation.*